# Firebase New Update

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, firebase, upgrade

so firebase has upgraded today I was using a free account for testing my ionic project app it says deprecated since may and it forced me to upgrade I did now I can' see any new documentation about angularJS what does that mean and what should I do, should I look for an alternative backend for my app -- I don't need much storage ... thanks

Comment: *firebaser here* We're working on releasing an [updated AngularFire](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#update_your_firebase_libraries_numbered). Aside from that, I'm not aware of any (new) problems with Ionic. If you find any, be sure to post a question with details.

Comment: ok it's working now few changes on Auth everything is fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst it is deprecated you could continue using it as is for now my project continues to work without issues.

However if you're moved over already you can't move back that I'm aware of.

To move your project over to the new version of Firebase there's a guide:

https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/

and all the new documentation is here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/

Answer (score 1):

I migrated a simple app yesterday just using the plain javascript APIs it works fine, some changes to the APIs but it was pretty straight forward

https://github.com/aaronksaunders/golftalk-sample

Answer (score 0):

As I read it you should just use the 'web' version: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup i'm not sure if anybody did a angular wrapper for it, so either use it as vanilla JS or you could create your own wrapper...

Actually it looks like angular fire is still supported... https://github.com/firebase/angularfire